# Capistrano Exception while executing as username@servername: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

I am in the process of trying to push my app to my server, I am running Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.4.6 and Capistrano 3. My past app was running on the server side Rails 4.2.

When I am trying to run `cap production deploy:check --trace` and getting:

```
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as username@servername: no implicit conversion of Array into String

Caused by:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pathname.rb:409:in `initialize'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pathname.rb:409:in `new'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pathname.rb:409:in `join'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb:81:in `block in join_paths'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb:81:in `map'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb:81:in `join_paths'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb:69:in `linked_files'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb:73:in `linked_file_dirs'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
```

Capfile:

```
require "capistrano/setup"

require "capistrano/deploy"
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/rvm'

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.6'

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git


require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  #Capistrano deployment gems
  gem "capistrano", "~> 3.10", require: false
  gem "capistrano-rails", "~> 1.4", require: false
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
```

Deploy:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "app"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:repo.git"

set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/appfolder"

append :linked_files, "config/database.yml"
append :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

set :keep_releases, 5

set :migration_role, :app
```

Production.rb

```
server "servername", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app db web}
```

I have looked around but have not seen anything on why I am getting no implicit conversion of Array into String. Have I put something wring into linked_dirs? If I need to add any other code, please let me know. I am not sure where to look at this point.

Comment: When I look in my capistrano.log the only thing I am seeing that is an error is : `Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
 DEBUG [7af8b979] Finished in 0.046 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).`

Answer (score 8):

If you print your variables `cap -p production deploy:check` we you will see that the variable `:linked_files => [["config/master.key"]]`  is a list of arrays and not a list of string.

You can change your line

```
append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
```